# Cannot send data over UDP in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, udp

I am trying to send the data over UDP in UWP Application. However, I cannot see the data being sent on Wireshark.

Just to check if firewall is causing any issue, I disabled it and tried sending the data again. However, I still don't see the data on Wireshark. Here's my code:

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
client.EnableBroadcast = true;
client.Connect(IPAddress.Broadcast, 9520);
Byte[] senddata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello!");
client.Send(senddata, senddata.Length);
client.Close();
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I am using Visual Studio 2017 to build this UWP Application.

Comment: Please consider using UTF8 instead of ASCII as your encoding... your future self will thank you.

Comment: Hi Peter,

Thank you for the input. I am new to developing Applications for Windows and my education background is not CS. Can you please elaborate on why UTF8 is better than ASCII? I'd love to know.

Comment: Basically, ASCII only encodes a small percentage of the world's languages. You won't be able to represent (eg) Chinese or Korean in ASCII, nor will you be able to support emoji etc. Check Wikipedia's entry in UTF8

Comment: Thanks Peter! Appreciate the input. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) explains why the above code will not work if the App capabilities were not configured.

I didn't configure the capabilities before asking this question. However, I came across [the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) and enabled some capabilities (Internet(Client & Server), Internet(Client), Private Networks(Client & Server)).

After configuring them, my earlier code is working fine.

If you're facing the same problem, please configure the capabilities by going to Package.appxmanifest -> Capabilities and then rebuild the solution. After correctly enabling the capabilities, your app shall send the data. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use codes below I write and test it, it works fine

```
        byte[] package= Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(udpInfo[2].ToString());
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(udpInfo[0].ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(udpInfo[1]));
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        try
        {
            sock.SendTo(package, ep); //send packet to sw ip
            Console.WriteLine("package sent");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("package can't sent");
            return false;
        }
```

**EDIT: udpInfo arraylist declaration below:**

```
public ArrayList udpInfo = new ArrayList(); // 0-ip 1-port 2-command
udpInfo[0] = "192.168.1.1"
udpInfo[1] = 1111
udpInfo[2] = "some commands"
```

Comment: Hi Mert Akkanat,

Thank you your input. I came across [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) that asks us to Declare the capabilities of the device in Package.appxmanifest file, which I didn't do before. Thus, the application wasn't sending any data out.

I now declared the capabilities and now, everything seems to work fine.